# Absolute positioning (with relative position container) with an image or nothing under it is affecting other divs

Tags: css, position, css-position, absolute

I don't really even know what my problem is anymore, but I'll try to explain it as best as I can.

Basically what I have is a two column layout. On the left is the content, which at present only contains a `h1` and filler text. On the right is the sidebar which should have a div in it (userinfobox).

The header text of the box is supposed to be outside the box a bit so I have the userinfobox `position: relative` and the header text `position: absolute`
Then, under that inside the box, there is a 150x150 image and then some more text below that.

Here's the HTML:

```
<!-- Main Content -->
<div id="contentwrapper" role="presentation">
    <div id="content" role="main">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        Content <a href="#">link</a>
    </div> <!-- content div -->

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div id="sidebar" role="complementary">
        <div id="userinfobox">
            <p id="header">User Info</p>
           <div id="userinfo">
           <div id="avatar"><img src="" id="tag" alt="tag" /></div>
            <p class="username">Username #</p>
            <p id="icons">Icons</p>
            <p id="membersonline"><a href="membersonline.php">Online Members (#)</a></p></div>
        </div> <!-- userinfo div -->
</div> <!-- userinfobox div -->
    </div> <!-- sidebar div -->
</div> <!-- contentwrapper div -->
```

And then the CSS

```
    /* Main Content */

     #contentwrapper {
        min-height: 400px;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        display: table;
        font-size: 1em;
    }

    #content {
        width: 669px;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
        display: table-cell;
        background-color: #F7F8F7;
        text-align: left;   
    }

    #content h1 {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 2.75em;
        line-height: 1em;
    }

    /* Sidebar */

    #sidebar {
        width: 234px;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
        color: #0D130D;
        background-color: #FDEBCF;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
 }
 #sidebar p#header {
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar p {
    max-width: 214px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* Logged In Sidebar */

#userinfobox {
    width: 214px;
    max-width: 214px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F7F8F7;
}

#avatar, #tag, #userinfo {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    outline: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#avatar, #tag {
    width: 150px!important;
    height: 150px!important;
}
```

That *should* be working, I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be; actually it *is* working, the sidebar anyway is doing what it's supposed to. But sometimes it pushes down the content (currently the `h1` and two words of text), almost to where the bottom of the 150x150 image would be.

I'll attempt to list the conditions that cause it to do this:

It does **not** work when:

- the avatar div is completely empty **and** the header is `position: absolute`
- the image has a src **and** the header is `position: absolute`

But, it **does** works when (seemingly regardless of absolute positioning of the header):

- the src of the image is empty
- there is no image, just text, in the avatar div (ie. just text in the entire userinfo div)
- the userinfo div is completely empty

I just don't understand how it's affecting something in a completely different div. Every place I've tried to search about this just talked about how absolutely positioned elements inside a relatively positioned element won't affect anything outside and how to use them. Also, this is a fixed width setup, so it's not like the width is changing at all; it is also not based on percent.

Comment: From your description it's hard for me to tell what your problem is as well. What exactly are you trying to accomplish that isn't working? PS - your divs are not floated as you claim. If you remove the `position:relative` and add `float:left` or `float:right` the divs will be floated and the header text is not pushed down (if this is even the problem).

Comment: Oops. Mea culpa! I forgot I changed that so there wasn't any floating. Sorry about that.

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Ok, here's it with an image in the src. The header is supposed to be aligned with the top of the userinfo box. http://jsfiddle.net/R8zAw/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `#content` div is using `display:table-cell;`, you must also apply `vertical-align:top;` to prevent your content from centering:

http://jsfiddle.net/R8zAw/3/

```
#content {
  width: 669px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-top: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #F7F8F7;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  vertical-align: top; /* add this */
}
```